# The Camel way of doing

Tags: apache-camel

I have a requirement where in i have to develop components using Camel. I know how to do this in pure Java. But i want to utilize Camel, wherever it is applicable. So here is a my requirement

```
1) Web service method       
2) Validate the request data
3) Insert data into DB
4) Export data into CSV File
5) Move the CSV into a FTP location
6) Call a Stored procedure (which takes a INPUT parameter from Request)
7) Call one more Stored procedure (which takes a INPUT parameter from Request)
8) Call a Web Service and I want this Web Service to run within certain time. If it takes more than that, throw out Time out exception.
```

Can we achieve this using Camel. I just want to know, whether we can do it or not. If you feel it is achievable, can you show me the right direction. Help appreciated.

Comment: Am able to do the first 4 steps using Camel routing. I used validator and File components.

Answer (score 2):

These are various basic tasks Camel is built to help you with.

Since Camel is well documented by both reference material and examples you can very easily find documentation online. Try it out and come back for detailed and specific questions. See some starting pages for your various tasks.

1. http://camel.apache.org/cxf-example.html
2. http://camel.apache.org/validate.html
3. http://camel.apache.org/sql-example.html
4. http://camel.apache.org/csv.html
5. http://camel.apache.org/ftp-example.html
6. http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html
7. DITO
8. http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html

Btw, you are receiving down votes since your question lacks some minor research effort, like searching the Camel online documentation.

Comment: Thank you Petter. If i want to execute these 8 steps one by one. I am struck as i dont have knowledge in this subject. For example  take steps 3 and 4. I already wrote a route like .to("file:data"), from this point for step 4, how can i do this. i mean how to append it with ftp

Comment: Most parts are very well documented - including doing an FTP transfer (`.to("ftp://user:pass@example.org/folder`). However, there are more to camel than this - you will need to know how to handle logging, debugging, trouble shooting, etc. You have some reading and learning ahead.. Simple as that.

Comment: Thank you Petter for your patience and time.